# Как распарсить многомерный массив JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Доброго времени суток, специалисты!
От сервера приходит многомерный массив в JSON'е (ajax). Вывожу в консоль, выглядит так:

```
 [[["Овечка12"],["Овечка13"],["Овечка14"]],[["Овечка15"],["Овечка16"],["Овечка17"]],[["Овечка18"],["Овечка19"],["Овечка20"]],[["Овечка21"]]]
```

Как добраться до его элементов? Пытался так:

```
 data[0][0][i]
 data[0][1][i]
 data[0][2][i]
 data[0][3][i]
```

Пробовал перебирать в цикле, но безуспешно. Направьте, пожалуйста, на путь истинный, дилетанта...

Answer (score 2):

```
var jsonObj =  [[["Овечка12"],["Овечка13"],["Овечка14"]],[["Овечка15"],["Овечка16"],["Овечка17"]],[["Овечка18"],["Овечка19"],["Овечка20"]],[["Овечка21"]]];

for (var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
  for (sheep in jsonObj[i]){
    alert(jsonObj[i][sheep]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Лучше будет, если Вы с PHP отдадите `Content-Type:application/json`, чтобы не делать JSON.parse(response)

Answer (score 2):

`JSON` это,на самом деле, ни какой не объект. Это строка, в которую зашифрован объект. Эту строку нужно расшифровать и тогда уже она станем объектом `Javascript`. 
Для распаковки используется метод `JSON.parse()`.
Попробуйте так.

```
var json = '[[["Овечка12"],["Овечка13"],["Овечка14"]],[["Овечка15"],["Овечка16"],["Овечка17"]],[["Овечка18"],["Овечка19"],["Овечка20"]],[["Овечка21"]]]';

var data = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(data);
console.log(data[0][0][0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Результатом будет одномерный массив через него проще добраться до элементов и делать с ними, что хотите.

```js
var json = '[[["Овечка12"],["Овечка13"],["Овечка14"]],[["Овечка15"],["Овечка16"],["Овечка17"]],[["Овечка18"],["Овечка19"],["Овечка20"]],[["Овечка21"]]]';

var data = JSON.parse(json);

function parseArray(arr) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      newArr = newArr.concat(parseArray(arr[i]));
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log( parseArray(data) );
```

Comment: Простите, я вообще слаб в javascripte. Я с сервера отправляю 4 массива в одном массиве. Подскажите пожалуйста как распарсить так, чтобы эти четыре массива были в разных переменных, просто их выводить в разных частях страницы надо. Спасибо.